# Python Pandas - Highest values from multiple columns of duplicated entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
A        B   C
entry1   10  3
entry1   7   5 
entry1   2   NaN
entry2   1   1
entry2   2   4
entry2   3   3  
...
```

In column A I have duplicated entries and I am interested to pick the highest values from column B and C for each entry. In case that `NaN` value exists, this overwrites the highest values.

Example:

For entry1, I would like to keep in the df just value `10` in **column B** and `NaN` in **column C**.

For entry2, I would like to keep in the df just value `3` in **column B** and `4` in **column C**.

I was thinking to sort the values and then to pick the last value like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B', 'C'], ascending=[False, True, True])
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='last'))
```

In this way, the remaining entry will have just the highest value for column B, not also for column C.

How I can achieve that as well?

Thank you.

Comment: use `groupby()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) the [`nan`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan) with [`inf`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf) then just take the [`groupby max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) to get the max value per group. Then [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the `inf` back to `nan`. This ensures that a `nan` value will be maximal per group since `inf` is:

```
cols = ['B', 'C']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(np.inf)  # replace NaN with largest value
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)[cols].max()  # Get Max Per Group
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(np.inf, np.nan)  # Return to NaN
```

Alternatively use a function or lambda to produce `nan` if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) values are NaN otherwise the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
df = (
    df.groupby('A', as_index=False)[['B', 'C']]
        .agg(lambda s: np.nan if s.isna().any() else s.max())
)
```

Both Produce `df`:

```
        A   B    C
0  entry1  10  NaN
1  entry2   3  4.0
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['entry1', 'entry1', 'entry1', 'entry2', 'entry2', 'entry2'],
    'B': [10, 7, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'C': [3.0, 5.0, np.nan, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0]
})
```

Comment: great answer as always +1. i don't have time to run timings atm but i'm curious about the various options. i'll try to do timings later.

Comment: @ me when you do I'd like to know as well. =)

Comment: @HenryEcker: I like your solution a lot. Thanks! Just tested it and it works!

Comment: @HenryEcker looks like there is an inflection point at ~10K rows where `groupby.max` overtakes `groupby.transform` (though it seems OP ended up needing your `agg` approach)

Comment: Thank you for running those timings I always like to know. Yeah the agg is certainly more readable, but also slow.